# cygwin char pointer and char address-------compare two scanf program

Tags: c, pointers, cygwin, scanf

I recently used cygwin and gcc a simple c program but something strange happens, I don't know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char in;
    scanf("%c",&in);
    printf("%c\n",in);
    return 0;
}
```

It output these:

```
$ ./a.exe
1
1
```

while next program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* in;
    scanf("%c",in);
    printf("%c\n",in);
    return 0;
}
```

It output these:

```
$ ./a.exe
1
▒
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in second code (read comments):

```
int main(void) {
    char* in;   // garbage value 
    scanf("%c",in);  // storing at garbage address
    printf("%c\n",in);  
    return 0;
}
```

`in` is an uninitialized pointer, pointing to a garbage location - Undefined behaviour.

Of course syntactically it is correct! you can use it as follows:

```
int main(void) { 
    char c;
    char* in = &c;  // pointing to valid address
    scanf("%c",in);   
    printf("%c\n", *in);  
    return 0;
}
```

Notice I change printf added `*`  dereference operator to print value

```
printf("%c\n", *in);  
               ^
```

To print address use `%p` and typecast address to `void*`

Answer (score 1):

Trying to scan into uninitialized pointer

Modify like this

```
char* in=malloc(1);
    scanf("%c",in);
    printf("%c\n",*in);
                  ^^ You should use *in to print the value
```